# Custom component dataGrid selectionMode as a property

Tags: apache-flex, datagrid

I have a custom component of which have a advancedDataGrid inside it. I want this component to be reusable so need is set the datagid selectionMode as a component property.

In mxml i want set property like this:

```
<comp:MyComp itemDataGridSelectionMode="singleCell" .../>
```

Inside MyComp actionScript i have a metatag like this:

```
[Inspectable(enumeration="singleRow, multipleRows, singleCell, multipleCells", defaultValue="singleRow")]
public var itemDataGridSelectionMode:String;
```

How do i bind this itemDataGridSelectionMode variable to advancedDatagrid selectionMode?

UPDATE: Here is a small test application fully working code:

```
<!--MyComp.mxml-->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Group xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
     xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
     xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" width="638" height="500">
<fx:Declarations>
    <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
</fx:Declarations>

<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        [Inspectable(enumeration="singleRow, multipleRows, singleCell, multipleCells", defaultValue="singleRow")]
        public function set itemsSelectionMode(value:String):void
        {
            this.adgItems.selectionMode = value;
        }

        public function get itemsSelectionMode():String
        {
            return this.adgItems.selectionMode;
        }
    ]]>
</fx:Script>
<mx:AdvancedDataGrid id="adgItems" designViewDataType="flat" width="100%" height="100%">
    <mx:columns>
        <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn headerText="Column 1" dataField="col1"/>
        <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn headerText="Column 2" dataField="col2"/>
        <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn headerText="Column 3" dataField="col3"/>
    </mx:columns>
</mx:AdvancedDataGrid>
</s:Group>

<!-- Application.mxml -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
           xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
           xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600" xmlns:comp="*">
<fx:Declarations>
    <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
</fx:Declarations>
<comp:MyComponent x="272" y="86" itemsSelectionMode="singleCell"/>
</s:Application>
```

Error: Invalid value: multipleRows. It must be one of singleRow, multipleRows, singleCell, multipleCells.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where you have your public var within your custom component, do this:

```
[Inspectable(enumeration="singleRow, multipleRows, singleCell, multipleCells", defaultValue="singleRow")]
public function set itemDataGridSelectionMode(value:String):void
{
   advancedDatagrid.selectionMode = value;
}

public function get itemDataGridSelectionMode():String
{
   return advancedDatagrid.selectionMode;
}
```

Comment: It still gives same error. It takes singleRow but not the others.

Comment: Builder gives error:  Invalid value: multipleRows. It must be one of singleRow, multipleRows, singleCell, multipleCells.

Comment: If you would of looked at the [API](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/advancedDataGridClasses/AdvancedDataGridBase.html#selectionMode), you would of noticed that "You must set the allowMultipleSelection property to true to select more than one item in the control at the same time."

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can set the itemDataGridSelectionMode as [Bindable] and then can bind it with the selectionMode property of the AdvancedDataGrid.

Comment: I tried that and gives an error:
Invalid value:  multipleRows.  It must be one of singleRow,  multipleRows,  singleCell,  multipleCells.

Comment: If this is the case then try using setters as suggested by @J_A_X

Answer (score 0):

One way is:

```
BindingUtils.bindProperty(datagridId, 'selectionMode', this, itemDataGridSelectionMode);
```

OR Use a setter method instead of variable definition.

Comment: The former solution is a horrible one since you're using binding in a place that it isn't needed.  The latter is the only real answer.